# Blender to Unreal Engine 4: How do i export my building from blender to unreal engine with the right collison?

Tags: blender, unreal-engine4

I have made a house (without roof yet) with some rooms in blender 2.9 and exported it to unreal engine 4. But in Unreal engine i can't move in it with the 3d standard third person character. I can only walk on it as it would be a closed cube or something.
What do i have to do, to be able to walk in it around?

Answer (score 0):

UE is automatically generating a convex (i.e. with no holes, caves, dents, openings, etc.) collision mesh that essentially wraps the whole model. Possibly just a cube. There are a couple of things you can do.

1. Open the mesh in UE and set the collision complexity to 'use complex as simple'. This isn't advisable unless the mesh is very simple as it uses every polygon in the mesh to query collisions against.

or

2. Create a set of collision meshes - one for each element of the house (walls, floor, etc.) - and bring them in with the model. These must be convex in shape. See here: [Static Mesh FBX Import](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/WorkingWithContent/Importing/FBX/StaticMeshes/index.html). You must follow the correct naming convention for the FBX import to recognise them as collision meshes.

If your house model has low enough a polygon count that you would end up with as many polygons in your collection of collision meshes, number 1 saves you the trouble of number 2 (and might even save some memory).

Don't forget everything needs to be triangulated.